# Set minimum value for input field Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, input, minimum

How do you set the minimum value for an input form field with type=>number. I have a count field that should have the MINIMUM value set as 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your options array, set "min" => "0"

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried specifying a min and max, as outlined in the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html)?

```
echo $this->Form->input('name', array(
  'type' => 'number',
  'min' => 5
));
```